# 2.92 - keyframe not matching typed in value - bug or feature?

Tags: animation

New to animating/ key framing.

Object selected, R (to rotate), Z (to lock), type "-370", press enter.

The object moves from 0° to 10° - I was expecting a full rotation and an additional 10 degrees.

Do I have something enabled causing this to happen?

Note; If I rotate the object using the 'Item - transform' panel, it seems to work just fine.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That is no bug. When you go over a 360 degree angle, it completes its round and resets the rotation. That is why you only have 0-10.

Comment: It seems a little odd as you are forced to use the transform panel, but at least I know why it is happening now. Thank you.

Comment: Strange. I can't reproduce this, in 2.92.

Comment: Perhaps I should try a fresh install. I'll do that after this project.